# How do you convert LPCWSTR to const char *?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2008

How do you convert LPCWSTR to const char *?

Thanks

Comment: Because he need it. I need it too. Example windows service written on VisualStudio2015 on c++ gives me startup params as LPCWSTR, but all my legacy code expects chonst char * array

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Use the [`WideCharToMultiByte`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd374130%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) function.

Note that `LPCWSTR` is the same as `const wchar_t *`, so if you're dealing with wide character data throughout your application, you may not need to convert it at all.

Answer (score 2):

You can also have a look at [wcstombs_s](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s7wzt4be%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)