# C win32 api unicode to ascii

Tags: c++, c, api, winapi, lpcwstr

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do you convert LPCWSTR to const char *?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4542521/how-do-you-convert-lpcwstr-to-const-char)

I have a function that gets a LPCWSTR string for win32 api usage.
Now I have a function that sends data in ASCII to the IRC server.
So now I need to convert it to ASCII, I haven't found any solutions, I only found ways to convert ASCII to UNICODE.

Answer (score 2):

[WideCharToMultiByte](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd374130%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) converts from UNICODE to MBCS. If your original wide char string consisted only of characters which could be represented in ASCII, then this will result in a ASCII string. 
You can also use [wcstombs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5d7tc9zw%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) which internally calls WideCharToMultiByte.

Either way, you will get a `LPSTR` or `char *` (which are the same).

Comment: Thanks :), I used the WideCharToMultiByte function with the UTF8 flag and it works.